# Warning on yum update

Tags: centos, yum, configuration, upgrade, plugin

I'm using centos 7, and when I want to run `yum update` console showing me below warning :

```
Configuration file /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/getpagespeed.conf not found
Unable to find configuration file for plugin getpagespeed
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
```

How can I remove first two warning ?

Comment: there's something strange here, because as far as I know, `getpagespeed` is a set of external yum repositories, not plugins. `GetPageSpeed` seems to be a (questionably related?) Russian IT service/web server blog thing? So, you seem to have set up a non-standard yum plugin, which even my google does not seem to know. How did you set up this plugin? You will have to disable it the same way.

Comment: Please post the output of `rpm -qa|grep yum`, the contents of `/etc/yum.conf`, relevant lines of `yum -v update` and check for references to `getpagespeed` in `/etc` by running `grep -Ri getpagespeed /etc`.